# How to change configSections, section, type element? Specifically Version

Tags: c#, configuration, configsection

I'm posting my question here and to CodeProject, as a [question](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/4263716/Customizing-section-tag-type-attribute.aspx) to the famous article series on the mysteries of config files.

From the article:

> Optionally, you may specify culture, version and public key (for
>   signed assemblies) values if you wish to ensure only a specific
>   version of an assembly is searched for when your .config  file is
>   parsed.

I'm using the following code to open and initialize the config file:

```cs
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = path;
config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
section = (OptionsSection)config.GetSection("myoptionsdata");
if (section == null)
{
    section = new OptionsSection(0, "aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc",14);
    config.Sections.Add("myoptionsdata", section);
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
}
```

That creates the following:

```xml
<configSections>
    <section name="myoptionsdata" type="my.namespace.OptionsSection, myAssembly,
      Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=111222aaaabbb"
      allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere"
      allowExeDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Allow"
      restartOnExternalChanges="true" requirePermission="true" />
</configSections>
```

Notice how the 'type' has Version, Culture, and the PublicKeyToken. I need to eliminate these, or at least the Version. The problem is that I deploy the app with a specific version, then I bump the version and issue updates. But when the read is done on the config it fails because the version is explicit.

So really all I want is this:

```xml
<configSections>
    <section name="myoptionsdata" type="my.namespace.OptionsSection, myAssembly" />
</configSections>
```

I have never once seen an example that includes the extended type values. Every example shows Save() creating type="namespace.class,assembly", and yet that doesn't seem to be the default behavior.

So, with reference to the above quote, where can I find information on managing those "optional" values?

For anyone googling, this is one of the causes of the infamous error below:

> Exception: An error occurred creating the configuration section
>   handler for myoptionsdata: Could not load file or assembly
>   'myAssembly, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=111222aaaabbb' or one of its dependencies. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\product\dir\name.config line 4)

I believe my question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001758) which so far has not received any response.

Going "off the menu", I just want to deploy a config file to a specific location (non-default) and allow users to set options in a Tools>Options sort of form. Most apps do this. Is there any easy and commonly accepted way of doing this? I should note that my app is an Outlook Addin, and I do my config file like this because I want to store addin settings in an addin-specific config file rather than anywhere near Outlook configs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assembly that contains your custom configuration section has a strong name. Strong-naming an assembly explicitly prevents the kind of in-place version upgrade you want to do. Remove the strong name from that assembly and the assembly loader will stop caring what version it is.

Comment: Completely missed that. Makes sense. However MS Office addins intended for a general audience must have a strong name. This question is answered (dang quickly too). But to complete the picture, it seems like the only way to get what I need here is to custom code the entire XML config file and just skip the FCL. Is that correct? THANKS!!!

Comment: Just define class with the appropriate public fields and use the DataContractSerializer on it. Really, the only benefit you get from ConfigurationManager is you don't have to manually open a file...

Comment: Agreed. I feel forehead-slapping silly. I'll just serialize a simple data class and not bother with XML or other complexities. Sometimes the easy answers elude us. Thanks for the clear thinking.

Comment: Another workaround, if you prefer to use the application configuration file is to implement custom config section in another assembly. Thus, if the config section assembly (strongly named) does not change, you have not to update its name in the configuration file.